# LINQ query not working in server,showing invalid identifier

Tags: c#, database, oracle, linq, server

I m working on a dot net project using oracle database where in a repository i have this LINQ query

```
var results = (from svd in context.SALESINVOICEDETAILs.Where(x=>x.INVOICENO==inv.INVOICECODE)
                               join pd in context.PRODUCTs on svd.PRODUCTCODE equals pd.PRODUCTCODE
                               //group pd by pd.BRANDID into grouping
                               group new { svd, pd } by new { pd.BRANDID } into grouping
                               select new
                               {
                                   price = grouping.Sum(x=>x.svd.UNITPRICE*x.svd.QUANTITY) ,
                                   discount = grouping.Sum(x => x.svd.DISCOUNT * x.svd.QUANTITY),
                                   brandId = grouping.Key
                               }
                                 ).ToList();
```

Now this works fine in my local pc.But when i implement this in server it's throwing exception

```
 {"ORA-00904: \"Project2\".\"BRANDID\": invalid identifier"}
```

if i comment out the price and discount it works fine also.it's giving exception running this two line

```
 price = grouping.Sum(x=>x.svd.UNITPRICE*x.svd.QUANTITY) ,
                                   discount = grouping.Sum(x => x.svd.DISCOUNT * x.svd.QUANTITY)
```

can anyone tell why this works fine in local pc but giving error in server? or solution of the problem

Comment: Are you connected to the same database in local machine and on the server?

Comment: yes.same database.

Comment: is DataModel same in both environment? if using different dll for datamodel.

Comment: datamodel mean?

Comment: i checked all my data reference(dll) with server.all the reference or dll are same as well as version

Comment: are you using the same database in local pc and server?
and can you check the underlying query that it creates in both cases?

Comment: yes same database.I checked a lot of times but no result.In "select new" anything query for 'svd' giving error but query on 'pd' gives no error [here 'brandid' is by which i grouped by the table.'brandid' is in 'pd'.svd is associated table which is 'grouped by' according to 'brandid' and aggregate function working on svd] @gilmishal

Comment: still no success after giving a whole day.don't know why behaving different in server,checked all reference which are same also.can anyone give any other idea ?

Comment: You say that databases are the same,but it should seems that when you are on the server you are pointing at a db without "grandid" table field...

Comment: **"without "grandid" table field."** ---I do not understand what do you mean by that @Ciro Corvino

Comment: sorry it was a mistake.. read "BRANDID". {"ORA-00904: \"Project2\".\"BRANDID\": invalid identifier"}

Comment: Can you query for `pd.BRANDID` in a simpler query or is it generally making problems on the server?

Comment: still don't understand .pointing at a db without brandid means what? @Ciro Corvino

Comment: i can get result of query of pd.brandid. All query for pd give result.any query or calculation involves svd in select new block gives 'invalid identifier' error @grek40

Comment: @MohammadSadiqurRahman simply if in remote env you are accessing to a different database from that you access from your local env.. check your remote and local config file comparing their connection keys.. if these keys are different, it is very likely that the remote db isn't updated.. and therefore you will have to add table column(s) that your entities are bound to (see PRODUCTs.BRANDID ).. hope it is clear..